# Javascript doesn't restart when paged landed on with back button (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile to show a listings page. When the page is first loaded some default HTML is in place. Then when the document is ready, an ajax query is fired off, the HTML it returned and inserted into the page.

When you then click on on of the list items it takes you to a details page. From there if I click the browser back button it returns to the listing page but the HTML I loaded from the ajax call is not there anyone, only the original default HTML.

Any idea why?

**Edit (to help clarify the problem):**

On the listing page I'm running this:

```
setInterval(function() { console.log("1 second"); }, 1000);
```

If I navigate to other pages with `data-ajax="true"` the time will start again on each page. If I go to a page with `data-ajax="false"` and then hit Chrome's back button the above Interval call won't start again. The page only shows the initial static HTML and doesn't trigger any inline javascript or appear to make any event calls.

Comment: Are you reading the URL anchors or something similar to load the appropriate page? If you don't, pressing back usually reloads the page. If you do, you need to make sure to always look for changes in the URL and reload what you need. Maybe cache it in the page

Comment: Give us some of your code. Without the code I can only guess whats going on in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
<body onunload="">
```

It will trigger a reload.

Comment: No luck. I added the following to the page code and it doesn't start again when I return to the page with Chrome's back button: setInterval(function() {console.log("1 second");}, 1000);